# Adding @Assert\All using form events in Symfon2

Tags: symfony

im just a newbie in symfony.

Im using symfony 2.0.23 in my application and I have the following assertion on my entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $discountLevelItems
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DiscountLevelItem", mappedBy="discountLevel", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @CustomAssert\Count(min="1", minMessage="Must provide at least one item.")
 * @Assert\All(constraints={
 *     @CustomAssert\UniqueInCollection(propertyPath="supplier", message="Duplicate suppliers are not allowed.")
 * })
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
private $discountLevelItems;
```

I want to remove the @Assert\All (which has a CustomAssert) and just add it during a particualar form event.

How can I do it?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution : Event Based.**

Remove Assert\All from entity

Add in your form as following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\All;
    // add this one in any event do you want.
    $builder
        ->add('field', 'fieldtype', [
            'constraints' => [new All(...)],
        ])
```

**Second Solution : Validation Groups**

I added `groups` modifier to your annotation below.

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $discountLevelItems
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DiscountLevelItem", mappedBy="discountLevel", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @CustomAssert\Count(min="1", minMessage="Must provide at least one item.")
 * @Assert\All(constraints={
 *     @CustomAssert\UniqueInCollection(propertyPath="supplier", message="Duplicate suppliers are not allowed.", groups = {'validation1'})
 * })
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
```

after this modification add `validation_groups => 'validation1'` to your form.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => '\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Demo',
        'validation_groups' => 'validation1',
    ]);
}
```

and in another form you can add validation_groups as validation2 the annotation would be disabled in form which has the validation2.

For more information please check : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html

Comment: can i do something like this :groups != {'validation1'} ?

Comment: You cannot but you can add multiple groups, `groups = { 'validation2', 'validation3'}` and add `'validation_groups' => 'validation1'` to your form. It would be fine.

Comment: if i add validation2, will that remove the Default validation group?

Comment: No Default is the global but when you don't specify Default in your form it would not process it

Comment: Your welcome if you have time please read http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/06/15/symfony2-using-validation-groups/ this it may give you better point and best practice, article mentions several cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from annotation, create a [callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) and implement your own logic.

Remember also that you can reach a similar behavior just using [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups)